# How do I mutate compileTime ref objects in Nim?

Tags: macros, compile-time, nim-lang

When I compile the following code it demonstrates that the `name` attribute of the `m` instance is set inside `setName` but then lost by the time the end of the program is reached.  How do I set `name` in such a way that it stays (like the `colors` seq does)?

```
import std/macros
type
  MyType = ref object
    name: string
    colors: seq[string]

proc newMyType(): MyType =
  new(result)

macro setName(m: static[MyType]): untyped =
  m.name = "foobar"
  echo "inside macro: ", $m[]
  newStmtList()

var m {.compileTime.} = newMyType()
static:
  m.colors.add("red")
  m.colors.add("yellow")
setName(m)
static:
  echo "at the end: ", $m[]
```

Output:

```
$ nim c -f --hints:off /tmp/samp
inside macro: (name: "foobar", colors: @["red", "yellow"])
at the end: (name: "", colors: @["red", "yellow"])
```

See that `name` is empty at the end. I want `name` to be `"foobar"` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`static` parameters are not mutable.

You can use a regular proc or a global.

```
var m {.compileTime.} = newMyType()

macro setGlobal() =
  m.name = "set global"

proc setProc(x: MyType) =
  x.name = "set proc"

static:
  m.setProc
  assert m.name == "set proc"

setGlobal()

static:
  assert m.name == "set global"
```

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but it's the right answer. Thank you! (I ended up going with a global while waiting for other insight)